# Unwanted text on created icon

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

[image: Unwanted text on icon]

I created a return icon while designing, but this text appeared on it. What is this text and how do I solve this?

There does not seem to be an error in my code, I searched the internet but could not find any results.I don't know how to investigate.

```
Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    // back icon
                    height: Get.height * 0.0494,
                    width: Get.width * 0.1,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: const Color(0xff2a2a2a),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    child: SuperTextIconButton(
                      'Back',
                      onPressed: () => Get.back(),
                      getIcon: Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                      buttonColor: const Color(0xff7ED550),
                    ),
                  )
```

Comment: I added the code fragment

Comment: Its is a overflowed error try to adjust  your  `Container` height and width

Comment: When I change the dimensions of the container, the structure of the icon is broken, is there any other method you can suggest?

Comment: The error should also be showing in your console log. As mentioned it indicates that widget is overflowing its parents dimension restrictions. Please provide the code of `SuperTextIconButton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is try to Wrap your `SuperTextIconButton` with a `FittedBox`.

```
Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                // back icon
                height: Get.height * 0.0494,
                width: Get.width * 0.1,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color(0xff2a2a2a),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                //edit this lines
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  child:SuperTextIconButton(
                    'Back',
                    onPressed: () => Get.back(),
                    getIcon: Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
                    buttonColor: const Color(0xff7ED550),
                   ),
                )
              )
```

if you want to know more details, refer to this [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) about `FittedBox`